# Datatables - Calculate Column Total when using Row Groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables. In addition to the regular table set up I am using datatables to add

**Row Groups**
- Outlined [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html)

**Column Totals**
- Using Footer Callbacled Outlined [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html)

I have a working Demo here **http://jsfiddle.net/c5UXe/**

Everything is working fine except my totals are being calculated 1 column off to the right (as you can easily see from demo) I am pretty sure the reason is because of the way groups works and is displayed.

I would like to display the totals under the correct column. i.e. shift all totals 1 column left to line up correctly.

The code used uses the first `<td>` in the row to use as the group name so for example

`<td>Joe Hammer</td>` is used as a group name.

This is the code I am using to calculate the totals

```
"fnFooterCallback": function (nRow, aasData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {

        var columnas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]; //the columns you wish to add            
        for (var j in columnas) {
            var columnaActual = columnas[j];
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++) {
                total = total + parseFloat(aasData[aiDisplay[i]][columnaActual]);
            }
            $($(nRow).children().get(columnaActual)).html(total);

        } // end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can fix it entirely through tweaking the JS.

Update the columns to add

```
var columnas = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

Then get columnaActual-1 instead of columnaActual

```
$($(nRow).children().get(columnaActual-1)).html(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Feels weird answering this myself, but just incase anyone else has the same issue here you go.

Updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c5UXe/1/

I added an extra `<th>` to the column total and I removed the 2nd `<th>` in column total via CSS setting the style to none.

I then Updated the Columns to add to this

`var columnas = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8]; //the columns you wish to add`

Removing the first `1` and adding number `8`

It is a pretty easy fix which mostly involved tweaking the HTML rather than the JS.

Comment: This appears to not account for multiple pages of data.

Comment: Beautiful  buddy.. you saved my life.. :)